# Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration /my-react-app/src/components/FirstExample/FirstExample doesn't exist

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to import my FirstExample component to app.js but I'm receiving an error message saying the module is not found.

my App.js

```
import FirstExample from "./components/FirstExample";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <FirstExample />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

the file I want to render is in the components folder:

```
import React from 'react'
import './FirstExample';

const FirstExample = () => {
  return (
    <div>FirstExample</div>
  )
}

export default FirstExample
```

File structure looks like:

```
src
  components (folder)
    FirstExample
      FirstExample.css
      index.js <-- this is the file I want to render
  App.js
  index.css
  index.js
```

I checked my import statement and it looks correct. Why is it saying the module is not found??

Comment: maybe your FirstExample.css, which is not a js module, try to put file extension on import inside your index.js...

`import './FirstExample.css'`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct behaviour.

You are trying to import FirstExample inside FirstExample component.
That makes absolutely no sense and I think is a typo from your side.

What you are propably wanting to do is to import FirstExample.scss

```
import './FirstExample.scss';
```